# Different behavior of gwt-maven-plugin in IDE and commandline

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am using the gwt-maven-plugin and since recently I got strange errors in my IDE (eclipse oxygen). After researching it I realize that the gwt-maven-plugin is behaving differently when run in eclipse or on commandline.
On commandline everything is ok and the gwt:css creates an interface with the correct visisbility (public). But when I run it in eclipse the `public` is missing and thus I get all the errors in eclipse since the classes can not access the interface anymore. I am using gwt 2.6.1, JDK 1.8.0 (but build itself is with 1.6) and maven 3.5.2.

Any ideas what is causing this?

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <goals>
    <goal>compile</goal>
    <goal>test</goal>
    <goal>css</goal>
    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
   <goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
 <skip>${gwt.skipcompile.config}</skip>
 <inplace>true</inplace>
 <module>${gwt.module.config}</module>
 <runTarget>Config.html</runTarget>
 <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
 <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
 <compileReport>true</compileReport>
 <cssFiles>
  <cssFile>MyCss.css</cssFile>
 </cssFiles>
```

```
//And the code is generated like this (eclipse):
interface MyCss extends CssResource ...

//in command line
public interface MyCss extends CssResource ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The `gwt-maven-plugin` delegates to GWT [InterfaceGenerator](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/css/InterfaceGenerator.java#L276) and it doesn't add the `public` modifier. You can see the git-log and confirm that this has been always the case (already reported [sometimes](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8952)). So, you cannot be executing the plugin goal from the command line, you should be using something different. For example, you might have a script that adds the `public` modifier using `awk` (or something similar), and this is not executed from eclipse.

Side note: You really should upgrade GWT and `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Thanks for the infos! But it doesn't seem to be fixed in a newer version, does it? Still strange, since if I execute it from commandline it is working. But from what I see it shouldn't...

Comment: but are you executing the mvn goal? and, is there some maven profile? or can you show the whole pom.xml configuration?